# Complex solutions of a system of polynomial equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a system of $n$ polynomial equations over $\mathbb{C}$ in $n$ unknowns and we know that it has more solutions in $\mathbb{C}^n$ than its Bezout's bound and, consequently, that it has infinitely many solutions. Can we conclude that the set of solutions (i.e. the associated affine variety) is not bounded in $\mathbb{C}^n$?

I believe the answer is YES and I have some rather muddy arguments to justify it, but I expect there must be a short clear proof.

Comment: By the sharp version of the Noether  normalization theorem (cf. Eisenbud's "Commutative algebra"), for every irreducible component $Z$ of  an affine algebraic subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, there exists an affine linear projection $Z\to \mathbb{C}^d$ that is finite and surjective.  Since every bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ has bounded image in $\mathbb{C}^d$ under an affine linear projection, the component $Z$ cannot be bounded in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: For a slightly different take, suppose $\mathbb{V}(f_1, \dots, f_n) = X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is bounded. Then $X$ is compact in the analytic topology, since it is closed and bounded. Considering $X$ as a scheme, it is therefore proper over $\mathbb{C}$, so in particular $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(f_1, \dots, f_n) = \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is finite-dimensional, hence artinian. Artinian rings have finitely many maximal ideals, so $X$ is necessarily finite.

Comment: I guess that's it! Thank you both for your answers.